# Can we merge .CSV file and .RAR file in hive (Hadoop tools)?

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

Can you suggest how we can do merging of different types of files ?

Comment: You cant. RAR isnt common in Hadoop anyway

Answer (score 1):

Merging of different types of files cannot be accomplished. Each file type has their own way of compression and storing data.

RAR file on the other hand is not usually used in Hadoop. If there are other formats like, parquet, orc, json - these can be merged by converting the files to the same type.

For example if the requirement is to merge parquet and json files, the parquet files can be converted into json using tools like `parquet-tools.jar` and can be merged by creating tables by loading these files into a table with appropriate schema.

Hope this helps!